# How to write html in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, document.write

I would like to write

```html
<body>
  <html>
    <div id="myfilter" style="position:absolute;background-color:#000000;opacity:0.3;width:100%;height:100%;display:none">
    </div>
    <div id="myrestartbutton" style="display:none;position:absolute;color:white;padding:20px;padding-top:0;border-radius:10px; top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);background:Black;">
      <h1>Score: 
        <span id="score">
        </span>
      </h1>
      <center>
        <button id="btn" onclick="restartGame()">Restart
        </button>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div id="canvascontainer">
    </div>
  </html>
</body>
```

in html only using a JS file, I would like my html file look like this :

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

I would like a pure JS way of doing this.

Comment: Also, your `<html>` tags should be the root tag. meaning, your `<body>` should be inside `<html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

```js
document.write('<body><html><div id="myfilter" style="position:absolute;background-color:#000000;opacity:0.3;width:100%;height:100%;display:none"></div><div id="myrestartbutton" style="display:none;position:absolute;color:white;padding:20px;padding-top:0;border-radius:10px; top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);background:Black;"><h1>Score: <span id="score"></span></h1> <center><button id="btn" onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button></center></div><div id="canvascontainer"></div></html></body>')
```

Comment: hmm I don't know why this did not work for me thx!.

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii In what way does it not work?

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii If nothing is displaying, that is because you set the display to none.

Comment: no yours worked, but when i did it did not.

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii Could you provide a [mre] of the issue?

Comment: is there a way i can add css to doc.write?

Comment: i got it and it works thank you! I figured out the problem I had doc.write go on page load.

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii No problem.

Comment: Heres what i needed it for https://dotgame-io.glitch.me/

Comment: Contain the ```body``` tag within the ```html``` tag......

Comment: whoops, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is not the approach suggested above. While it does work, technically, there are whole frameworks out there which help building HTML with client-side Javascript performing all the DOM manipulation.
As a result, you can mix JS code with HTML in brand new ways.

Check this out:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_jsx.asp

It has all the feel of HTML, but is rendered through the JavaScript runtime. The key thing is, you don't have to write low-level JS code, but outsource that to the framework, spending your time on larger higher-level problems.

Comment: I agree with you Alex. hiiii is definitely a beginner. Though, maybe not specifically react, any framework ( even jQuery ) will work for him for what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii As well as React + similar frameworks, definitely take a look at jQuery, it's more beginner friendly and its super easy to import and start using in your code. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Comment: Hello, i would like to change a element in js canvas, I want it to change on click 
it will look like MODE: "change text here function" (this will be in top left of canvas, thx.
{[Only asking here b/c out of Questions]} (plz don't ban or strike me)

Comment: @hiiiiiiiiii look at a w3 schools tutorial about using the JS canvas, you can find plenty of references and examples online

Comment: i did not find anything to help me.

Comment: plz view https://support.glitch.com/t/canvas-text-change-on-btn-click/44060